# Python Postgres Package: psycopg2 copy_from vs copy_expert

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Requirement: To load millions of rows into a table from S3 using Python and avoid memory issue

I see there are two methods  psycopg2's copy_from and copy_expert.

Which of these are most efficient and avoid memory issue

Also, I see that Redshift(Which is Postgres) support COPY Command to load data from S3 file but not sure if Postgres DB support such feature

Comment: First the community Postgres does not support `COPY` directly from `S3`. Second `copy_from` vs `copy_expert` is not really the issue. That will be the network lag from ` S3` and streaming the rows.

Comment: Whats main difference b/w `copy_from` and `copy_expert`, my understanding is both does the same functionality of loading data from the file into a table

Comment: The difference is the  `copy_from` has a subset of the `COPY` options available, whereas  `copy_expert` allows you to submit your own  `COPY` string with your choice of options. For more detail see full commands starting [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

Answer (score 3):

My implementation changing `copy_from` to `copy_expert`. Extensive analysis of PostgreSQL load can be found here: https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql.

COPY_FROM

```
def insert_with_string_io(df: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str):
        buffer = io.StringIO()
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)
        buffer.seek(0)
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor.copy_from(file=buffer, table=table_name, sep=",", null="")
            except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
                print("Error: %s" % error)
```

COPY_EXPERT

```
def insert_with_string_io(df: pd.DataFrame):
        buffer = io.StringIO()
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)
        buffer.seek(0)
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor.copy_expert(f"COPY <database>.<schema>.<table> FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER false)" , buffer)
            except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
                print("Error: %s" % error)
```